# I am trying to load data from a txt file and load it into a binary search tree, then printing it

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to load data from a txt file and load it into a binary search tree, then printing it, expecting the .txt contents as an output. Then, i tried clearing/freeing the tree contents, then printing it again, expecting an empty output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct account
{
    char *email;
    char *password;
    struct account *left;
    struct account *right;
}
account;

account *insertAccount(account *root, char *email, char *password);
account *createAccountNode(char *email, char *password);
account *loadAccountDat(void);
void clearAccount(account *root);
void printAccountTree(account *root);

// Account bintree
account *accountRoot = NULL;


int main(void)
{
    accountRoot = loadAccountDat();
    printAccountTree(accountRoot);
    clearAccount(accountRoot);
    printAccountTree(accountRoot);
}

account *createAccountNode(char *email, char *password)
{
    account *newNode = (account *) malloc(sizeof(account));
    newNode->email = email;
    newNode->password = password;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;

    return newNode;
}

account *insertAccount(account *root, char *email, char *password)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        return createAccountNode(email, password);
    }
    if(strcmp(email, root->email) < 0)
    {
        root->left = insertAccount(root->left, email, password);
    }
    else if(strcmp(email, root->email) > 0)
    {
        root->right = insertAccount(root->right, email, password);
    }
    return root;
}

void clearAccount(account *root)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    clearAccount(root->left);
    clearAccount(root->right);

    free(root);
}

// For testing
void printAccountTree(account *root)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    printAccountTree(root->left);
    printf("%s || %s\n", root->email, root->password);
    printAccountTree(root->right);
}

account *loadAccountDat(void)
{
    if(checkAccountFile() == 1)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    account *root = NULL;
    FILE *f = fopen("account.txt", "r");
    char *email = malloc(25 * sizeof(char));
    char *password = malloc(25 * sizeof(char));
    char buffer[255];

    // Scan every line in file and put into binary tree
    while(fgets(buffer, 255, f))
    {
        sscanf(buffer, "%[^;];%[^\n]", email, password);
        root = insertAccount(root, email, password);
    }
    fclose(f);
    return root;
}
```

After loading and storing the txt file contents into the binary tree with the loadAccountDat function, I tried printing the tree and only get 1 line of data from the original txt file to be printed.

Then, after clearing the tree, I tried printing the tree and i got segmentation fault problem

Comment: One problem is that you only have one instance of the `email` and `password` arrays, shared between all your nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>[Assuming the question is about the crash]</sub>

The crash happens because you have *undefined behavior* in your code.

You `free` all nodes, but you never set `accountRoot` to `NULL`. That means the second call to `printAccountTree` will dereference an invalid pointer.